# Deployment of Visual Studio Web API on IIS server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dns, iis-7, hosts

Im in trouble again. Please be gentle with me, cause Im not an expert -yet.

In Visual Studio, I have made a web api which works as intended.
To move the project to the production server, I publish the project to filesystem ( a local folder on my personal computer).
Now I move these files to the server (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mydomain)

Then I have edited the host file

```
   127.0.0.1       mydomain.com
   127.0.0.1       www.mydomain.com
```

In the IIS, I have created a new website with:

```
 Bindings:
 Type = Http
 IP address = All unassigned
 Port = 80
 Hostname = www.mydomain.com

 Application pool:
 Name= mydomain.com
 .Net CLR version = .Net CLR version v4.0.30319
 Managed pipeline mode = integrated.
```

When I ping (Commandprompt on the IIS server) the url I get answer:

```
 C:\Windows\System32>ping www.mydomain.com
 Pinging www.mydomain.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
 Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

 Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
   Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
   Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When I try to browse, then I get the following error message:
This Page Cannot Be Displayed

The host name resolution (DNS lookup) for this host name ( www.mydomain.com ) has failed. The Internet address may be misspelled or obsolete, the host ( www.mydomain.com ) may be temporarily unavailable, or the DNS server may be unresponsive.

Please check the spelling of the Internet address entered. If it is correct, try this request later.

If you have questions, or if this condition persists, please contact your organization's network administrator and provide the codes shown below.

I have a SamplePage.aspx page in the folder:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="SamplePage.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="SamplePage" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
 <html>
 <head runat="server" >
    <title>Code-Behind Page Model</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:Label id="Label1" 
     runat="server" Text="Label" >
  </asp:Label>
  <br />
  <asp:Button id="Button1" 
     runat="server" 
     onclick="Button1_Click" 
     Text="Button" >
   </asp:Button>
     </div>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I call this (with the IIS IP it processes SamplePage.aspx http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mydomain/SamplePage.aspx

UPDATE:
I've read this page
https://forums.iis.net/t/1026696.aspx?IIS7+localhost+Page+Cannot+be+Found
And the thing is if I stop the "Default Web Site" then Im no longer able to process http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mydomain/SamplePage.aspx

UPDATE 2:
I have just tried the same procedure at IIS on my local computer with exactly the same result Notification codes:  (1, DNS_FAIL, www.mydomain.com)
I must be doing something wrong. But what could it be?

Comment: Is your browser trying to hit http**s** instead of http?

Comment: @kettch no only http

Comment: Also verify that there is no https redirect. You might also try explicitly binding the site to 127.0.0.1 instead of all IP's. It seems like I've read that that address isn't normally valid.

Comment: @kettch 127.0.0.1 gives the same result. Can you tell if my procedure is as supposed?

Comment: What you are doing is a normal process, please check status of this url  www.mydomain.com/mydomain/SamplePage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now solved.
The .net version of the IIS was not up to date
Based on this article:
[ASP.NET IIS 7.5 HTTP 500.21 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952115/asp-net-iis-7-5-http-500-21-error)

I followed the instructions and pasted these two lines into the commandprompt (as administrator):

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

And then it worked perfectly.
Thanks for your inputs of a rater general problem description.